# configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'creds' in Python

Tags: python, config, telegram-bot

I'm getting  configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'creds

Config.cfg file

```
[creds] 
token = telegram_bot_token
```

code.py file

```
class telegram_bot() :
     def __init__(self,config):
         self.token=self.read("config.cfg")
         self.base="https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(self.token)

    def read(self,config):
        self.parser=cfg.RawConfigParser()
        self.parser.read(config)
        return self.parser.get('creds','token')
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MAINSERVER.PY", line 5, in <module>
    bots=telegram_bot("config.cfg")
  File "G:\BOT\TBOT\bs4\qrcode\main.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.token=self.read("config.cfg")
  File "G:\BOT\TBOT\bs4\qrcode\main.py", line 24, in read
    return self.parser.get('creds','token')
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\configparser.py", line 781, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\configparser.py", line 1149, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section) from None
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'creds'
```

Anybody know what could be the issue ?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually reading the file? Try printing the entire config object before you looking up a particular session.

Comment: File is `Config.cfg` but you read from `config.cfg`, maybe that's the problem

Comment: @user3365922 (s)he is on windows, nobody cares about the upper/lower case

Comment: It's returning "NoSectionError ", It is not related to filename.I checked @user3365922

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016479/python-configparser-nosectionerror-no-section)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016479/python-configparser-nosectionerror-no-section/35017127