# pathlib absolute path misbehaving with config parser

Tags: python, cron, configparser, pathlib

I have a following python3 script, that uses the **config** function to load data from a txt file that sits in the same directory where the script is located.

I've implemented the **configparser** module to extract the data, and **pathlib** module to set the absolute path to that file

```
from pathlib import Path

try:
    import ConfigParser as configparser
except:
    import configparser

def config():
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config_file = Path('config.txt').resolve()
    parser.read(config_file)
    return parser
```

then i pass it as an argument to the next method, which then gets the needed variables from the
config file:

```
def search_for_country(config):
    country_name = config.get("var", "country_name")
```

the config.txt file is structured like this:

```
[var]
country_name = Brazil
```

The problem is: everything works fine if I run the script via Terminal from the same directory, but eventually it is intended to be run as a cron job, and if i try to execute it from one directory above, it returns the following error:

```
File "test/script.py", line 28, in search_for_country
    country_name = config.get("var", "country_name")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 781, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 1149, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section) from None
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'var'
```

Which seems to be telling that it cannot find the txt file.

So far I've tried out different options, for example using **parser.read_file()** instead of **parser.read()**, also tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35017127/13363008

But none seem to be working. Maybe anyone could think of a cause to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for Your problem :

```
import pathlib

path_own_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
path_conf_file = path_own_dir / 'config.txt'
assert path_conf_file.is_file()
```

but why to store such config as text in the first place ?
"config is code" - so why limit Yourself with text config files ?

my usual way is :

```
# conf.py
class Conf(object):
    def __init__(self):
        country_name: str = 'Brazil'

conf=Conf()
```

```
# main.py

from .conf import conf

print(conf.county_name)

# override settings in the object
conf.county_name = 'Argentina'

print(conf.county_name)
```

it has so many advantages like having the correct data type,
having the IDE hints, avoiding the parsers, dynamically change settings, etc ...